# Which MySQL table type for online library and review?

Tags: database-design, mysql

What is the best table type for a MySQL database which is holding information for a book library and review site?

Comment: operational database? innodb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by table type, but if you are looking for a sample schema, it might be something like this:

```
users
id,first_name,last_name,username,password_hash,password_salt,email,...

books
id,...

reviews
id,book_id,user_id,...
```

**Edit:**

See [here](http://www.kavoir.com/2009/09/mysql-engines-innodb-vs-myisam-a-comparison-of-pros-and-cons.html) for a comparison of InnoDB vs MyISAM

Comment: Table type as in: InnoDB or MyISAM...?

Comment: InnoDB supports foreign key constraints, so I would go with that.

Comment: Do I need foreign key constraints. It is going to be a very simple site...

Comment: Foreign Keys will ensure that you maintain data integrity. It will be a lot easier down the road.